# IndexError: index 100 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 8

Tags: python, indexing

I'm very new to Python. I'm getting the following index error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "Pride.py", line 109, in <module>
plt.imshow(X_train[i,0], interpolation='nearest')
IndexError: index 100 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 8
```

Here's the code:

```
print('X_train shape:', X_train.shape)
print(X_train.shape[0], 'train samples')
print(X_test.shape[0], 'test samples')

# convert class vectors to binary class matrices
Y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train, nb_classes)
Y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test, nb_classes)

i = 100
plt.imshow(X_train[i,0], interpolation='nearest')
print("label : ", Y_train[i,:])
```

I'd appreciate some help as I am quite confused.

Comment: it says you're trying to access the 100th element from an array with 8 positions.
what happens when you try `len(X_train)`?

Comment: Does "len(x_train) "replace "i=100" or come after it? Where do I write this line?

Answer (score 0):

try doing something like

`if (len(X_train >= i):
    plt.imshow(X_train[i,0], interpolation='nearest')
    print("label : ", Y_train[i,:])`

to avoid errors like this

Comment: Does that mean I have to remove i = 100?

Comment: you could try making `i=7` for checking if it works

Comment: please remember to upvote answers that work well for you :)